# How does one determine the representation of an object from its indices?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, representation-theory

Given a multi-index object with multiple types of indices, is there a general process to determine what representation it would transform under?

As an example, consider the group $G = Spin(5,5)$ and two of its representations $R_1 = \mathbf{16}$ and $R_2 = \mathbf{10}$. Let lowercase Latin indices index $R_1$ and Greek indices index $R_2$ such that $a,b,\ldots = 1,\ldots 16$ and $\alpha, \beta, \ldots = 1, \ldots, 10$.

Given a spinor $\Lambda^\alpha$ in $\mathbf{16}$ and an expression

\begin{equation}
0 = \Lambda^\alpha (\gamma^{ab})_\alpha{}^\beta \partial_\beta
\end{equation}

how does one determine the representation of $(\gamma^{ab})_\alpha{}^\beta \partial_\beta$? Here, $\gamma$ is symmetric in the $R_1$ $\text{indices}^\dagger$ If I've understood the source correctly, it should transform in $\mathbf{45}$ but I am failing to see how that is so. If I were pushed for a guess, I might give $Sym(\mathbf{16} \otimes \mathbf{16}) \otimes \mathbf{10}$ but this would appear to be wrong. Does the contraction on $\beta$ affect its representation?

Perhaps the representations of this particular group are well-documented. If so, how would one approach the problem if $G$ were a more esoteric group whose structure you did not know?

(For context, the above appears in the paper arXiv:1306.2643 [hep-th], eq. 5.48)

---

$\dagger$Footnote: I may have misunderstood this symmetrisation bit. Unfortunately, the authors change notation half way through and I'm not sure if I've interpreted it correctly. Apologies but, nonetheless, the question still stands.